# Facebook share og:image

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, share

i have a problem with og:image. Like i'm developing an facebook app and there is some steps in app. At last step user should share image that he/she created. But when i send url to created image to header for og:image, on share screen image can not be displayed. How can i solve this porblem? By the way i used debugger tool and there isn't any image either.

here is my debug link; http://corpusad.com/ecard/ecard/template_preview/64

Comment: Pass your URL though the [Facebook debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). It will alert you to any problems with the `og:tags` on your page.

Comment: At the moment, it looks like you have a PHP error on that page, other than that the image you provided is too small and also there seems to be a problem with the location of your `og:tags`.

Comment: hi thanks for comments. First i passed url to debugger already. There isn't any error. It seems like normal. And the image's width and height that i provided is 735x425px. And here is my header.php with some parameters that i passed. http://pastebin.ca/2488055

Comment: Well - when I looked at your URL through the debugger there were errors. You've changed it since - but there are still problems that the debugger is warning you about. Please read all of the information there before asking for help here. All the information you need is right there in the debugger - as I said before - your image is too small!

Comment: my friend i read all informations. You say; my image is too small but the image that i provided is 735x425px in header og:image tag not small than 200x200. I checked it out. There's randomed image on debugger. I don't really understand that where this small image is comes from.

Comment: Hehe... I didn't tell you anything :) This is what the debugger is saying. Look at the size of the image you are provifing: `https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p75x75/851578_455087414601994_1601110696_n.png` - that's really small. 75x75

Comment: :) again im telling you. im providing for example; http://corpusad.com/ecard/uploads/overlay/4211017.png?fbrefresh=gMn image not https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p75x75/851578_45508741460‌​1994_1601110696_n.png. I don't have an idea where that 75x75 image comes from. og:image tag in my header.php is like <meta property="og:image" content="http://corpusad.com/ecard/uploads/overlay/4211017.png?fbrefresh=gMn"/>. So my image doesnt appears on facebook share :(

Comment: Can you please create a NEW url that does not redirect to anywhere but still contains the `og:tags`? Perhaps that is what is confusing the debugger. Also - when I viewed your raw HTML, the `og:image` tag is empty. Are you calculating what image to show dynamically? Perhaps you should try using a hardcoded value to ensure that everything is working correctly. Once you see that things are working you can change it to use dynamic `og:tags`

Comment: yes i am sending created image url dynamically to the og:image tag. What do you mean with hardcoded value? Thanks for helps by the way :)

Comment: No problem :) You say that you are selecting the correct `og:image` dynamically - so you can try to place a hard coded value to an image instead of dynamically creating it (just to test that everything is working).

Comment: understand now. When i write any image's url to og:image tag directly it's working. But when user create an image and clicks on save button this created image not showing on share box. But url of created image is true in og:image tag that i send dynamically.

Comment: If it works with a hard coded value but not with your dynamic one - then the problem is most likely in your code that decides what image to show...

Comment: do you have any advice for that? url of image is true in og:image tag. But as you say can't decides to show it. How can i handle it? I'm really confused.

Comment: I don't now how you are dynamically selecting the image - it all depends on your application.

Comment: okay i'll check my application again and again. Thanks for helps and advices :)